# Add custom classes to "wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id)" wordpress function

Tags: wordpress

I can get images using wp_get_attachment_image($attachment_id) wordpress function.It automatically add below code.

```
<img width="150" height="150" src="http://localhost/test2/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/pexels-photo-1308624-150x150.jpeg" class="attachment-thumbnail size-thumbnail" alt="">
```

I want to add "alt" and another class using this function. To be specific I want to generate code like this.

```
<img width="150" height="150" src="http://localhost/test2/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/pexels-photo-1308624-150x150.jpeg" class="attachment-thumbnail size-thumbnail custom-class" alt="Some Alt Value">
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can pass it like this.

```
<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, 'thumbnail', "", ["class" => "my-custom-class","alt"=>"some"]); ?>
```

You can read the full documentation here.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image/

Answer (score 2):

You can pass mulitple attributes, for a custom class you can do:

```
<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image($image_id, 'full', false, array('class' => 'my-custom-class')); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure someone else will bump on this; the classes can be space separated so that multiple classes can be added.

```php
<?php 
echo wp_get_attachment_image($image_id, 'full', false,
array('class' => 'my-custom-class class2 class3'));
?>
```